# How do I make a database request from a liquid app proxy page?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-liquid

I'm new to Shopify development so please forgive me if I'm misunderstanding how this should work, but I'm working on an app that has a user-facing frontend and have run into a roadblock. To start off with some backstory, I'm trying to make a classifieds page that can be accessed from the frontend, and will still integrate with the existing theme (so header, footer, etc are imported from the shop's theme), and the data gets populated from a database I have set up. Then from the admin page, the listings can be removed/whatever else needs to be done by an admin.

I'm developing this for a theme that doesn't have theme extension functionality (so no app blocks), so after doing some research it seems like an app proxy that returns a liquid file is my best bet. I've modified the Shopify QR code app example to have an app proxy running on the same server, and currently have it returning a .liquid file after everything has been verified. This is where I'm a bit confused, as I tried using a `{ javascript }` tag so I can make a request to my database end points and populate everything accordingly, but it would give me an error saying that tag doesn't exist (even though it exists [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/tags/javascript)). Am I going about this wrong, or am I just missing something? There's another app that uses the same idea, where it routes to /a/<appname> and displays custom data that can make a request to a server so I know this method is possible, I guess I'm just a little lost on the implementation of it. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy can return JSON data. So instead of returning Liquid, return JSON and then use your front-end code to render that data into your theme using whatever templates you like. Handlebars for example work well.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding this correctly, if I go this route would that involve having the shop create a new page for my app and adding <div id="whatever">, then my app would use ScriptTags to inject my code within that div? I was wanting to create individual pages for each listing to view more details, so the main page shows all active listings (for example, at `/a/classifieds`), then clicking on it would take you to `/a/classifieds/<listing_id>`. If I were to use ScriptTags on a single page that wouldn't be possible, right?

Comment: Would I be able to use ScriptTags on a proxy page that returns Liquid, and have certain end points return json for retreiving data and others returning Liquid? For example, if my proxy is set up so `/a/classifieds` and `/a/classifieds/<id>` both return liquid, then `/a/classifieds/<id>/json` returns json for the data, would I be able to modify the page on `/a/classifieds/<id>` with ScriptTags to fill in the data?

Comment: You should really use a theme app extension. Script tags are dead, no longer valid, and therefore you're left with extensions. You can use a proxy inside extensions. So you're covered there.

Comment: Even with a theme extension, isn't that only able to be added to premade pages in the form of an app block? I can't find anywhere showing a way to use a theme extension to add pages as needed. If it matters at all, I wasn't planning on publishing the app as it will be designed around a specific shop's current theme, so I thought in that case using ScriptTags shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: You can enable the extension to pages. Therefore, the merchant can create a page for classifieds, and add your extension to it. All else in terms of content can then be from your extension. It is neat. Clean. And again, forget script tags, they're DOA these days.